# Loading different markers based on values using Google Map API in Angular 7

Tags: angular, google-maps, marker

I have an application that retrieves the list of participants from a database and display them in the map using Google Map API. The returned data is like below:

```
[
    {
        "id": 25,
        "firstName": "D",
        "middleName": "",
        "lastName": "Test",
        "lat": "39.2424525",
        "lng": "-76.5124078",
        "fullAddress": "132 main st baltimore maryland 21222",
        "zip": "21222",
        "draggable": false,
        "enrollments": [
            {
                "id": 9,
                "provider": "test",
                "zone": "zone18",
                "participantId": 25
            }
        ]
    }
...
]
```

The html code that I use for the map is:

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">

    <agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [zoom]="zoom">

      <agm-marker *ngFor="let m of participants" 
        [latitude]="m.lat" 
        [longitude]="m.lng" 
        [markerDraggable]="m.draggable"
        [iconUrl]="{
          url: mrk,
          scaledSize: {
              width: 45,
              height: 50
          }
        }"
        >

        <agm-info-window>
          <strong>Name: {{ m.firstName }} {{ m.lastName }}</strong>
        </agm-info-window>
      </agm-marker>

    </agm-map>

  </div>
</div>
```

The component is

```
export class MapResultComponent implements OnInit {
    participants: any[] = [];
    mrk;

    constructor(
     private participantService: ParticipantService
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
      this.loadParticipants();
    }

    private loadParticipants() {
      this.participantService.getAllActiveMap().subscribe(participants => {
         this.participants = participants;
         this.mrk = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png';

        for (let i = 0; i < participants.length; i++) {
          if (participants[i].enrollments[0].zone === 'zone7') {
            this.mrk = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png';
        }
       }

      });
    }

}
```

I know that this is not a good approach. Since I have `zone7` field in the returned data, all markers are now becoming red. What I would like to achieve is the color code by zones. Which means the same zones will have the same marker icon. The zones are plain categorical text like zone1, zone2, zone3.... zone24.
How can I change the icon of the marker based on their zone fields? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How else do you want to do it? You need to map zones with icon names somehow... You could have local marker icons and name them after your zone names and use it like `this.mrk = participants[i].enrollments[0].zone + '.png';` ...

Comment: Each participant has zones which a categorical data. The code that I have and you provided give me to change marker for all of them. I need participants that are in the same zone represented by the same marker and so on. I have 24 zones. I can accomplish by loading all of them separately or one-by-one, which is not an efficient way to do it.

Comment: That's exactly what I said. If you have 5 markers in "zone21" you can load them with the marker `zone21.png` or whatever goes... That's one way. There are many ways. Your question is too broad as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by adding ternary operators in the `[iconUrl]` as below:

```
[iconUrl]="{
  url:  m.enrollments[0].zone === 'zone10' ? 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png' : 
        m.enrollments[0].zone === 'zone17' ? 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/yellow-dot.png' :
....
          scaledSize: {
              width: 45,
              height: 50
          }
        }"
```